# PDFSharp - Extract FlateDecode as PNG

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

**Goal**
To properly get FlateDecode image objects from pdf out at png.

Please let me know if you see anything wrong with the below code that might be causing issues.

The code below gives me the image but it is completely distorted. See: (left = good, right = mine with code)

[image]

```
static void ExportAsPngImage(PdfDictionary image, string filename, ref int count)
    {
        int width = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.Width);
        int height = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.Height);
        int bitsPerComponent = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.BitsPerComponent);

        var canUnfilter = image.Stream.TryUnfilter();
        byte[] decoded = image.Stream.Value;

        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pixelFormat;
        switch (bitsPerComponent)
        {
            case 1:
                pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed;
                break;
            case 8:
                pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
                break;
            case 24:
                pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown pixel format " + bitsPerComponent);
        }

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
        var bmd = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, pixelFormat);
        int length = (int)Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToInt32(width) * bitsPerComponent / 8.0);
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            int offset = j * length;
            int scanOffset = j * bmd.Stride;
            Marshal.Copy(decoded, offset, new IntPtr(bmd.Scan0.ToInt32() + scanOffset), length);
        }
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);
        using(var fs = new FileStream(filename + "_" + count + ".png",FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
         bmp.Save(fs, ImageFormat.Png);
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: You assume specific color spaces. Why?

Comment: Just random testing code -  PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfArray arr = image.Elements.GetArray(PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfImage.Keys.ColorSpace); removed same result @mkl

Comment: Can you post a link for the PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an `case 8` image. If you extract the image data without the associated color palette and display the image with the default color palette, then you will get images like the one you are showing.

Images in PDF files can consist of several PDF objects: the pixel data, the color palette, an alpha mask, a bilevel mask.

Maybe for that image it is sufficient to create a grayscale palette where color x has the RGB values (x, x, x). But for a general solution extract the palette from the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

here's a snippet of code which will set the palette for a /DeviceRGB colorspace:

```
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced;

...

// get palette if required (pf is the pixel format, previously extracted from the imageDictionary, imageDictionary is the PdfDictionary for the image, bmp is the System.Drawing.Bitmap we're going to be dumping our image data to)
if (pf == System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
{
    PdfArray colArr = imageDictionary.Elements.GetArray(PdfImage.Keys.ColorSpace);
    if (colArr != null && colArr.Elements.GetName(0) == "/Indexed" && colArr.Elements.GetName(1) == "/DeviceRGB")
    {
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette pal = bmp.Palette;      // this returns a clone, so we'll manipulate it and then set it back at the end
        int palCount = colArr.Elements.GetInteger(2);
        char[] palVal = colArr.Elements.GetString(3).ToCharArray();
        int basePointer = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < palCount; i++)
        {
            pal.Entries[i] = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(palVal[basePointer], palVal[basePointer + 1], palVal[basePointer + 2]);
            basePointer += 3;
        }
        bmp.Palette = pal;
    }
    else
    {
        // some other colorspace mechanism needs to be implemented
    }
}
```